# Can't get form to submit in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a selection option in my form that I know is deterring the form from submitting.  I can't figure out why though.  Here is the snippet that is causing an issue:

```
<%= f.select(:state_id, options_for_select(State.all.map {|p| [ p.home_state, p.id ]}), :label => "State", :class => "dropdown-menu")%>
```

Here is the rest of the form:

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Profile') %>

<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Name' %>
<%= f.number_field :age, :placeholder => 'Age' %>
<%= f.form_group :sex, label: { text: "Sex" } do %>
<br>
  <%= f.radio_button :sex, 'Male', label: "Male", inline: true %>
  <%= f.radio_button :sex, 'Female', label: "Female", inline: true %>
<% end %>

<%= f.text_field :city, :id => 'gmaps-input-address', :placeholder => "City" %>

<%= f.select(:state_id, options_for_select(State.all.map {|p| [ p.home_state, p.id ]}), :label => "State", :class => "dropdown-menu")%>

<%= f.submit "Submit", :class =>'btn btn-primary' %>


<% end %>
```

Any help is always much appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you see? What is the deterrence? what comes up in logging on the Parameters in the server when you submit?

Answer (score 0):

If anything, you should look at the [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) helper:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Name' %>
    <%= f.number_field :age, placeholder: 'Age' %>
    <%= f.form_group :sex, label: { text: "Sex" } do %>
       <%= f.radio_button :sex, 'Male', label: "Male", inline: true %>
       <%= f.radio_button :sex, 'Female', label: "Female", inline: true %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_field :city, :id => 'gmaps-input-address', placeholder: "City" %
    <%= f.collection_select :state_id, State.all, :home_state, :id, prompt: "State", class: "dropdown-menu")%>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

You'll also want to post any console logs you may have received for the request. Remember that computers are logic-based, they're not emotional and will only stop working if there's an error. Your job is to find the error and fix it, hence showing what's going on with your code infinitely helps, where guesswork doesn't :)